# Should you hash users password if you're not storing it?

Tags: flutter, dart, security

I was wondering if there is a point to hashing users password, if you don't store it anywhere in the application. I use firebase auth to authenticate my users, where they input their email and password, and then I pass those credentials as arguments to repository functions and then to the firebase sdk.

I've seen some discussions about people advocating for password hashing, but all of them were in context of dart servers, and stuff like banking apps, while I'm making a simple notes app. I do think that it probably won't hurt, but I wouldn't want to add another package dependency, which doesn't do much.

Is there any point in encrypting the password in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a third-party authentication service like Firebase Authentication, where user credentials are handled entirely by Firebase and you don't need to store or manage user passwords yourself, there is typically no need for you to hash the passwords in your application. Firebase Authentication takes care of securely storing and managing user credentials.